# PHP - Words with hashtag don't get echoed on my page

Tags: php, post, get, hashtag

I have a simple link that opens a PHP page and searches for keywords, but if my code is like:

```
https://example.com/search.php?s=#cool
```

And I use:

```
echo $_GET["s"];
```

in my `search.php` page, the echo is empty. Instead, If I use words without hashtags, I can successfully echo them.

Is there a way to allow **#** in a PHP GET like that, so that I can get properly show data based on hashtag keywords?

Comment: You need to properly URL-encode values like this - if you don’t, then `#` _obviously_ marks the beginning of the fragment portion of the URL, meaning any possible query string _ends_ there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hashtag in a url is meant for a hash of the url. A hashtag will not be recognised as part of the GET parameters.

What you can do is urlencode the string.

If you replace the hashtag with %23 it will come out as a # again later on (because php already urldecodes the output)

```
https://example.com/search.php?s=%23cool
```

and then:

```
echo $_GET["s"];
```

Comment: No, do _not_ urldecode on the receiving end - PHP has already done that for all data it provides via $_GET.